# whats wrong with my code tampermonkey google chrome

Tags: github

I want add a button to go to Github source page from the raw of a file and here is the code:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        From Raw To Github
// @namespace   From Raw To Github
// @description Add a button to go to Github source page from the raw of a file
// @include     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var rawURL = window.location.href;
var [_, repo, path] = rawURL.match(/https?:\/\/raw\.githubusercontent\.com\/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)\/(.+)\/.+/);

var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "https://github.com/" + repo + "/tree/" + path;

var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Go to Github folder";

a.appendChild(button);

document.body.insertBefore(a, document.body.firstChild);
```

and here is the error:

[image]

What's wrong?